# How can retrieve users custom fields only?

Tags: users, custom-field

I have created fields for users and also entry type.
I want to get only users fields. I have retrieved custom fields but that returns all the fields.

```
$users = \craft\elements\User::find()->id(USERID)->one();
print_r($users->getbehaviors()['customFields']);
```

I know how to get user custom fields with field Handle.
I need only users fields (whole users fields not single) that admin assign in the CP. ( settings/users/fields ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by going via the element's field layout:

```php
$user = \craft\elements\User::find()->id(1)->one();

$fields = $user->getFieldLayout()->getFields();
```

This will return you an array of all the fields (fields, **not** values) attached to your user.

Comment: yes It is working. Thanks man..